# How to get items from ComboBox to ListBox

Tags: c#

I've problem that I can't find answer to. Basically I have a ComboBox and a Listbox. What I need is that when I select and item from ComboBox, for example item named "Label", items like "Font", "ForeColor" will appear in Listbox. How do I do that? I've tried to do it like this:

```
listBox1.Items.Clear();
if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 3)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add("Fonts");
}
```

...But nothing happened.

Comment: *Where* is this code contained? It needs to be in comboBox1's [`SelectedIndexChanged`'s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You need to harness the ComboBox's [SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event. From there, you will known which item was selected in the ComboBox then you add that item to your ListBox.

Did I get that right ?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to change the contents of the list box when the selected item in the combo box changes. So, you need to add an event handler for the combo box. You need to handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    switch (comboBox1.SelectedIndex)
    {
    case 0:
        // add some items to the list box 
        break;
    case 1:
        // add some other items to the list box 
        break;
    // etc. etc.
    }
}
```

This is very similar to the code in your question. Presumably your code does not work because it is attached to the wrong event handler.

Comment: Right now what will happen is that the selected item from combobox will appear in the listbox. I don't think that you completely understood what I need to make the programm do.

Comment: Not trying to be cocky or anything, but which part of my question you did not understand?

Comment: Never mind, I can't even count properly. Sorry. Everything works perfectly. Thanks for your help. ;)

Comment: Good. My initial confusion was I tihnk down to the title of the question, "How to get items from ComboBox to ListBox".